# How to `whitelist-package` with Payara Micro Bundle?

Tags: java, payara, payara-micro

According to this [blog article](https://blog.payara.fish/resolving-library-conflicts-with-class-whitelisting), in order to use Google Guava with Payara, it needs to be "whitelisted", however, how to `whitelist-package` with Payara Micro Bundle?

The application `web.xml` does not accept `<whitelist-package>com.google</whitelist-package>`

Comment: Check out this one: https://medium.com/@abangkis/how-to-fix-guava-problem-when-deploying-firebase-admin-to-payara-afefc6d0a777 It basically suggests you to create a glassfish-web.xml file in the same folder of your web.xml file which will whitelist the packages. Worth to try!

Comment: @OnurBaştürk yes I tried it, it breaks the app and won't even load doing that.

Comment: Let me ask: which version of Google Guava do you want to use? The one you provided within your source code or the one provided by Payara? And what's the version of your Payara server? In the post you provided, it says that whitelisting began with 171th release

Answer (score 0):

You only need to whitelist the Google Guava library if you want to use the version that is already bundled in Payara Server. If you'd rather want to use Google Guava library that is present in your application WAR, you can do one of the following:

- disable classloading delegation (always load any classes from your app, only loads classes from Payara server if they don't exist in your app)
- enable the whitelisting mechanism and include only packages that should be loaded from Payara Server, e.g. org.glassfish (don't include Guava). All the other packages would be loaded from the application

If you whitelist `com.google` like in your example, Payara Server won't search for that package and subpackages in your application and only attempt to load the classes from Payara Server. This is I think the opposite of what you want.

For more info about classloading in Payara Server (including classloading delegation and whitelisting), see the docs at https://docs.payara.fish/community/docs/5.2020.4/documentation/payara-server/classloading.html.